# JSON parsing with PHP - most efficient way

Tags: php

I send JSON object to server. On server side I have to parse this obj with PHP.

I'm stuck in the loop. I don't know how to proceed inside loops.

Im looking for most efficient way to parse this object and save all variables into DB.

```
[
{"ADI":{"id":-1,"danger":0}},
{"ADI":{"id":3,"danger":0}},
{"ADI":{"id":3,"danger":0}},
{"ALE":{"_id":1,"_name":"Milk","contain":false}},
{"ALE":{"_id":2,"_name":"cfg","contain":false}},
{"ALE":{"_id":4,"_name":"Lakt","contain":false}},
{"PRO":{"image":"","code":"123456","name":"jfbj"}},
{"USER":{"email":"spam@spam.com"}}
]
```

For now I have done this:

```
$string = file_get_contents('php://input');

$array = json_decode($string, true);
//print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $t => $index) {
   foreach ($index as $vas => $r) {
     //Here I'm stuck!!!
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to `json_decode()`? Why?

Comment: Seems you're going right...What exact problem you facing ?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? And where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed inside loops

Comment: I think you can try var_dump() it will show you where you "are" in the variable

Comment: In loops you write more code with relation to the value (`$r`) and the key (`$vas`). For example you run an SQL insert with that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can grab values from json

```
<?php
$string = '[
{"ADI":{"id":-1,"danger":0}},
{"ADI":{"id":3,"danger":0}},
{"ADI":{"id":3,"danger":0}},
{"ALE":{"_id":1,"_name":"Milk","contain":false}},
{"ALE":{"_id":2,"_name":"cfg","contain":false}},
{"ALE":{"_id":4,"_name":"Lakt","contain":false}},
{"PRO":{"image":"","code":"123456","name":"jfbj"}},
{"USER":{"email":"spam@spam.com"}}
]';
$array = json_decode($string, true);
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($array);exit;
for ($i=0;$i<=(count($array)-1);$i++){
    //print_r($array[$i]);
    if (array_key_exists("ADI",$array[$i])) {
        $ArrVal = $array[$i]['ADI'];
        $id = $ArrVal['id'];
        $danger = $ArrVal['danger'];
        echo "$id,$danger ";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);

for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  if(isset($array[$i]["ADI"])){
    print_r($array[$i]["ADI"]);
  }

  if(isset($array[$i]["ALE"])){
    print_r($array[$i]["ALE"]);
  }
}
echo "</pre>";
```